# How to use x:Key in an Xpath in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xpath

I've been trying to write the correct Xpath query but I can't seem to get it correct. It always errors or returns null...

I have a XAML file that includes something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="settingsBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource overrideButtonMouseOver}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="64" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="64" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="28" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="690" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Img\settings.png" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

I need to return the "ImageBrush" node but only if `x:Key` of `Style` is "settingsBtnStyle"
I used XPath Visualizer to make sure I have the correct Xpath and it is:

```
ResourceDictionary/Style[@x:Key="settingsBtnStyle"]/Setter[@Property="Background"]/Setter.Value/ImageBrush
```

Now in WPF I wrote

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText(xamlPath);
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(txt);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

var test = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("ResourceDictionary/Style[@x:Key=\"settingsBtnStyle\"]/Setter[@Property=\"Background\"]/Setter.Value/ImageBrush", manager);
```

Visual Studio keeps crashing, telling me

> "Namespace prefix 'x' is not defined.

How do I define that namespace/fix the Xpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query an XmlDocument without getting a 'Namespace prefix is not defined' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509864/query-an-xmldocument-without-getting-a-namespace-prefix-is-not-defined-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the namespaces to the `XmlNamespaceManager`. This should work:

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("def", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

XmlNode test = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//def:Style[@x:Key=\"settingsBtnStyle\"]/def:Setter[@Property=\"Background\"]//def:ImageBrush", manager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I finally got it working but I don't know if it's efficient. I had to add two namespaces to the manager:

```
manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
manager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
```

I then had to add `ns1:` before each element like so:

```
var test = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns1:ResourceDictionary/ns1:Style[@x:Key=\"settingsBtnStyle\"]/ns1:Setter[@Property=\"Background\"]/ns1:Setter.Value/ns1:ImageBrush", manager);
```